# Exporting maps at high resolution for a specified area

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cartography, export, resolution

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and am very new to it. I have Bing Maps aerial imagery of a particular road intersection and I want to export the map as a TIFF at a 1:1000 scale. When I zoom in and then use Export map feature only the area which I can see on screen gets exported. If I zoom out into the whole study area I get a very bad resolution TIFF. I know the top, bottom, left and right extent of my area in meters. Now, my question:

Is it possible to get multiple images (at 1:1000 scale) of the area - like tiles -  that can be joined to get the whole area map? A detailed procedure description highly appreciated.

Comment: not detalied, but a good place to look http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000097000000

Answer (score 1):

check out the data driven pages toolbox. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003m000000
depending on the shape of your AOI, you'd create a grid index feature or strip map index of your AOI and use that to inform data driven pages. 
there are a few youtube demos e.g.,  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ocrHUhjV0 or an esri has a free training seminar http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseid=2152
hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating many individual maps and then combining, have you attempted the following:

1. Creating a Layout with an extremely large page size (one large enough to accommodate the extent you hope to generate an image for)
2. In layout view, changing the data-view scale to 1:1000

If your extents are not too large and you can identify the right page size, this should give you a single image of the area of interest at the 1:000 scale you are interested in.